# Can I use for loop in _.filter, if not is there any solution in lodash.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am using lodash.js in my project, to get a filtered list from a collection "applicationuser". I am using `_.filter` method in my js file, initially I am getting an array of records to `vm.user=[user1,user2,user3,user4]` then I want to get filtered list from applicationuser which contains the userid belongs to vm.userid. Usually when I use `_.filter` method when I have to compare with only one value like this

```
    vm.userlist= _.filter(applicationuser,function(user){
    return user.userid= vm.user.userid
    });
```

But at this situation I have to compare with array of users user id as I mentioned above, I wrote for loop in above code as

```
    vm.userlist= _.filter(applicationuser,function(user){
    for( var i=0; i<vm.user.length; i++)
    {
    return user.userid= vm.user[i].userid
    }
    });
```

But I am getting unfiltered list (means all records from applicationuser).

Comment: can you post a sample data ?

Comment: i have two tables named applicationuser and user , in applicationuser table userid is foreign key it has repeated multipletimes for different applications, so based on the userid's i am getting to vm.users , i want filter the applicationuser table data.( sorry i am new to stackoverflow, can't send as diagram).@Mritunjay

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you can achieve the same with lodash way.

```
vm.userlist= _.filter(applicationuser,function(user){
    return _. some(vm.user, function(vuser){
         return vuser.id == user.userid;
    });
});
```

> The [some](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) function checks whether or not any element exists in the array which matches the predicate. Iteration is stopped once predicate returns truthy.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhso1v8r/)

Comment: You could replace the predicate for call to `some` with matches iteratee: `{id: user.userid}`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing = instead of == (assignment instead of comparison).

```
vm.userlist = _.filter(applicationuser,function(user){
return user.userid == vm.user.userid
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for lodash, but the algorithm you're proposing has `O(n^2)` runtime, which isn't good.

You can get `O(n)` runtime if you store `userid` values in a hashset (all JavaScript `Object` instances are hashsets) and use the `O(1)`-runtime `in` operator:

```
var allUserIds = {};
for( var i = 0; i < applicationuser.length; i++ ) {
    allUserIds[ applicationuser[i].userid ] = i; // storing the value `i` is arbitrary, you could also just store `null` or `true` some other value.
}

vm.userlist = _.filter( applicationuser, u => u.userid in allUserIds );
```

You don't need lodash for this really - you can use vanilla JavaScript (ECMAScript 5 or above) using `Array.prototype.filter`:

```
vm.userlist = applicationuser.filter( u => u.userid in allUserIds );
```

### Update:

After looking at the lodash documentation, lodash has this functionality built-in as the `uniq` function, which you can use in one-line, without needing to manually create your own hashmap object:

```
vm.userlist = _.uniq( applicationuser, u => u.userid );
```

Comment: i don't get all userid's to vm.users, i am getting only 10 from total 2000 userid's, i think i didn't ask properly, because  i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @nikil It's still important to avoid `O(n^2)` runtime complexity. If your targeting a database you should use SQL or an ORM instead of loading every record into memory (which is what it sounds like) because then your application will be very, very slow - and it will suffer from concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

lodash filter return true/false if you want the item is on your filtered result. You can rewrite your code as follow:

```
vm.userlist= _.filter(applicationuser,function(user){
    return _.filter(vm.user, function(u) {
       return u.userid == user.userid;
}).length>0;
    });
```

Comment: This still has `O(n^2)` runtime. If `applicationuser` contains 1000 elements then this code will iterate over the users 1,000,000 times (in the worst-case).

Comment: I see, It's a lazy code, we should extract the userid into an array to lookup. I read your solution, it's best solution ;)

Comment: @nikil: Nice to hear about that but it's better if you use Dai solution.